# Can i add mongodb _id to localhost adress to display one post from database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, express, axios

I have set up my project to display posts from a MongoDB database. My localhost address is `http://localhost:5000/api/posts` and it displays my two saved posts. How can I add MongoDB _id to localhost adress to only display one post?

MongoDB _id: `6061890d59ec3b6abcb011fb`

I have tried this:

1. `http://localhost:5000/api/posts/6061890d59ec3b6abcb011fb`
2. `http://localhost:5000/api/posts/id:6061890d59ec3b6abcb011fb`
3. `http://localhost:5000/api/posts/_id:6061890d59ec3b6abcb011fb`

All of them returns error `Cannot GET` /api/posts/and_the_above_parameters_for_each_example`

`Index.js` to connect my backend to my application.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const posts = require("./routes/api/posts");

app.use("/api/posts", posts);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

`posts.js` to connect to MongoDB database. Below Password, MY_DATABASE and TABLE is changed to real values in my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const router = express.Router();

//Get posts
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await loadPostCollection();
  res.send(await posts.find({}).toArray());
});

//Add post
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await loadPostCollection();
  await posts.insertOne({
    text: req.body.text,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });
  res.status(201).send();
});

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await loadPostCollection();
  await posts.deleteOne({
    _id: req.params.id,
  });
  res.status(200).send();
});

async function loadPostCollection() {
  const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://MongoDB:PASSWORD@cluster0.5pnzd.mongodb.net/MY_DATABASE?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );

  return client.db("MY_DATABASE").collection("TABLE");
}

module.exports = router;
```

`PostService.js` to display posts on localhost and methods to post and delete.

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/posts/";

class PostService {
  // Get posts
  static getPosts() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios
        .get(url)
        .then((res) => {
          const data = res.data;
          resolve(
            data.map((post) => ({
              ...post, //spread operator
              createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt),
            }))
          );
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

  // Create posts
  static insertPost(text) {
    return axios.post(url, {
      text,
    });
  }

  static deletePost(id) {
    return axios.delete(`${url}${id}`);
  }
}

export default PostService;
```

Comment: Please share more details. You can do a lot of things, but this might depend on whatever software you use to display the items

Comment: Please show how are you handling that in your routes. please show some backend code

Comment: Most likely you simply don't have a route for this.

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem. As you are doing so, please also adjust the tags of your post. I would assume that [tag:localhost]  is unrelated, while adding a tag for the programming language or framework is missing

Comment: @NicoHaase my searches haven´t given me any luck and I´m stuck. Can you please point me in any direction?

Comment: As we said, you're missing a route for "get a post", which is different from "get all posts". Should be similar in implementation to "delete a post", which you do have.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1: `http://localhost:5000/api/posts/6061890d59ec3b6abcb011fb` is correct, but you're going to need to create a new route to handle that request.

These are often called 'show' routes.

```js
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  // code to handle the logic of that request
  // access the url parameter via: req.params.id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await loadPostCollection();
  res.send(await posts.findOne({
    _id: req.params.id,
  }));
});
```